# How to use maas to create disk partitions in batches

Tags: maas

Hell All

I plan to use Maas to install the operating system (Ubuntu 20.04) on 100 servers
The default partition on Maas can't meet my needs. I need to use a custom partition

/boot/ 1G

/ 100G

/var/log/ 50G

/data other size

At present, I can only manually partition one by one and then deploy
Is there any way to deal with it in batches?

Maas version=2.9

Thank you for your help

Comment: seems to be not that simple as we would like https://caribou.kamikamamak.com/2015/06/26/custom-partitioning-with-maas-and-curtin-2/